# how to pass JS Object to json

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am new to jade.

I have a route as below

```
var fortunes = ['a','b','c'];
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    var temp = fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.length)];
    res.render('about',{fortune:temp});
});
```

how to use fortune as key in the jade file?

Sample Jade code I have tried:

```
html
    head
        title = "about"
        body
            p1 This is fortune page
            blockquote #{fortune}
```

HandleBars code which is working.

```
<h1>About fortune</h1>
<p>Your fortune for the day:</p>
 <blockquote>{{fortune}}</blockquote>
```

How to use the object keys directly in jade?

Answer (score 0):

```
html
    head
        title = "about"
        body
            p1 This is fortune page
            blockquote!= fortune
```

And don't forget to configure your app to use jade engine

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Comment: are you getting any error...even in developer console @starkk92